# How to add row in Ionic dynamically for even column number

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, ionic-framework

I want to create a table of 2 columns using Ionic grid and Angular's ng-repeat. Please see my code below:

```
<div ng-repeat="category in vm.categories">
    <div class="col col-50">
      <div class="list card">
        <div class="item item-image">
          <i class="{{category.image}}" style="{{category.style}}"></i>
        </div>
        <a class="item item-icon-right positive" href="#">
          <i class="icon ion-eye"></i>
          {{category.name}}
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I am getting categories from backend, I thought, adding col-50 class by default creates a row if 2 col-50 classes are added, but its not working.

Comment: I got the solution at the following link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26688086/create-row-every-after-2-item-in-angular-ng-repeat-ionic-grid