# how to display image horizontal and vertical dynamic

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, html

I wanna display images in imageList.

I wanna see

- AB
- CD

How can i do that?
It is not about even or odd

maybe list can be like below
ABCDE
FG

I just wanna new row or display:block when count==2 .List can be (1,1,1,1,2,1 ) First row 4 elements Second row 2 element.List can be (1,1,1,2,1,2,1) Then First row 3 elements Second row 2 elements Third row 2 element

Link is here
 *****jsfiddle.net/jpkwhfv3/ *****

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create Row every after 2 item in Angular ng-repeat - Ionic Grid](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26688086/create-row-every-after-2-item-in-angular-ng-repeat-ionic-grid)

Comment: Can you provide some more info? Which version of Angular? Angular 1 or Angular 2 or higher?

Comment: it is angular 1

Comment: I just wanna new row or display:block when count==2 .List can be (1,1,1,1,2,1 ) First row 4 elements Second row 2 element.List can be (1,1,1,2,1,2,1) Then First row 3 elements Second row 2 elements Third row 2 element

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this :

```
  <div ng-repeat="key in items">
    <div class="row" ng-if="$even">
      <div>{{items[$index]}}</div>
      <div>{{items[$index + 1]}}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

with

```
$scope.items= Object.keys(m);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/0momap0n/302/

Comment: Thanx but it isn't about even or odd . It's about count1 or 2. Every lines maybe isn't equal. I just wanna new row when count==2 .List can be (1,1,1,1,2,1 ) First row 4 elements Second row 2 element.List can be (1,1,1,2,1,2,1) Then First row 3 elements Second row 2 elements Third row 2 element

Comment: Are the list elements either 1 or 2 ?

Comment: List elements has name. But lines are seperated by counts(1 or 2) you can think true or false jsfiddle.net/jpkwhfv3 A, B, C, D is not important list can be grow