# How to repeat directive with different step condition

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an array of objects. I want to display two object per row. Something like:

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="twoObject in objects>
    <div class="col-sm-6">{{twoObject(1).name}}</div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">{{twoObject(2).name}}</div>
</div>
```

As you know here `{{towObject(1)}}` is not valid code.

How can I achieve this in angularJS?

Comment: so what is wrong with this? or give detail of objects

Comment: You can find an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26688086/create-row-every-after-2-item-in-angular-ng-repeat-ionic-grid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed this issue using the following trick:

```
<div ng-repeat="object in objects">
    <div class="row" ng-if="$even">
        <div class="col col-6">{{object[$index]}}</div>
        <div class="col col-6">{{object[$index + 1]}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is where I got it: [Create Row every after 2 item in Angular ng-repeat - Ionic Grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26688086/create-row-every-after-2-item-in-angular-ng-repeat-ionic-grid)